# Українські крилаті вислови-логогрифи

Tags: фразеологізми

Аналізувала латинський афоризм-логогриф *Amore, more, ore, re* - *Любов, характер, слова, вчинки* (повний вислів **Amore, more, ore, re amicus cognoscitur** - *Друг пізнається з любові, звичок, мови та справ*). Зацікавило питання існування подібних українських логогрифів.

Знайшла [підбірку віршів Віктора Марача](http://gak.com.ua/creatives/2/32430), загадки у роботі [ЛІНГВОДИДАКТИЧНІ ІГРИ «ЦІКАВА ФОНЕТИКА» НА УРОКАХ УКРАЇНСЬКОЇ МОВИ В 5 КЛАСІ](http://www.yrok.net.ua/_ld/5/583_Bk1.pdf) Надії ПАНЬКОВОЇ, учителя-методиста Немішаївської загальноосвітньої школи № 2 І-ІІІ ступенів,
Бородянського району Київської області, та у дослідженні ["Гра словом у творчості сучасних українських поетів"](https://urok-ua.com/hra-slovom-u-tvorchosti-suchasnyh-ukrajinskyh-poetiv/).

А от чи видавався колись збірник логогрифів українською мовою, що стали крилатими висловами?

Answer (score 2):

Окрема збірка не потрапляла мені до рук. Хоча, є кілька збірників крилатих фраз та висловів. Цікаво, що один і той же вислів в різних куточках України матиме доповнення або буде коротшим.Непоганою книгою є "Українські приповідки" збірки В.С.Плав'юка, Едмонтон, 1996 р.